# Taskbar flashes grey

Tags: update

After an update a few months ago, the taskbar on the desktop disappeared and was replaced with a flashing grey bar.

I am running Jessie and am getting the following errors when running an update:

```
sub process returned with error code (1)
dependency problems
xserver not configured yet
```

and several other error messages relating to x-server components not being configured or present.

How do I sort this lot? I'd rather not reinstall because I've got a LAMP setup for local testing of websites and don't want to have to set it all up again.

I have looked at this [page](https://bigdanzblog.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/raspberry-pi-taskbar-xpanel-flashes-grey-for-non-pi-user/), but it is not relevant, looking in `/etc/group` pi is in the audio group.

Comment: Thanks for the answers which have eventually come in. I ended up reinstalling with a new image so I can't test anyone's answers. Unfortunately this means I can't mark anybody's answer as correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `dtparam=audio=on` to `/boot/config.txt`
by [fzinken](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/alsa-doesnt-work-after-last-update/10600)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. While you may explain what steps to take you have not explained what your proposed fix does or why it should work. Your link is broken as well.

Comment: +1,thanks my taskbar goes back. I've got this problem right after `rpi-update`.

Comment: The link works fine!

Answer (score 1):

As per [this page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36869/taskbar-flashes-grey), it could in fact be an audio problem so I suggest instead:

`sudo usermod -a -G audio <your_user>`

At any rate, that's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I eventually ended up reinstalling with a new image so I can't test your idea. I guess this means I can't mark your answer (or anybody else's) as correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with **QEMU** and **Raspbian Wheezy** (fully upgraded), and eventually solved removing the following block from `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel`:

```
Plugin {
        type=volumealsa
        Config {
        }
}
```

Probably this is caused by an **audio problem**, because QEMU says:

```
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
```