# Taskbar flashing white after firmware update (4.4.7v7+)

Tags: gui, firmware, taskbar

I'm running an RPi 2 B and just updated my firmware (to 4.4.7v7+ #877), and now the taskbar (or what should be the taskbar), is just a flashing white rectangle.  I've tried rebooting a few times with no luck.  What's worse, whenever I maximize command line windows, those flash as well.  I tried running the `startx` command, and received the following errors:

```
Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <LALT> has 2 symbols
Ignoring extra symbols
Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
```

I read the post that relates this to an audio problem and executed the command

`sudo usermod -a -G audio <your_user>`

without success.

Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it?

Comment: have you seen this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36869/taskbar-flashes-grey

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes, no luck there either.  I updated my post mentioning this as well.

Comment: Did you try the other answer? It was downvoted because it was little more than a link not because of a flaw in the answer?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Ok, that actually worked.  If you submit it as a solution here (without the dead link), and maybe explain why you think it works, I'll upvote and accept as the answer.

Comment: policy is to mark this as a duplicate. and link to the other Question. Feel free to upvote the question and answer that worked. You can also upvote and add comments as needed. I am just glad I could help.